# Does intelligence depend more on environment than on genetic factors?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, evolution, evolutionary-game-theory, intelligence

Many have argued that the test of IQ is simply a test of language. The application of the test consists of asking a number of questions. The person should understand the question presented to them and should be able to answer the questions properly. If a person does not understand the question or do not know to answer or give a wrong answer it results in a negative point.

is there a genetic component in this equation?

Comment: Which "equation" are you asking about? ‘When data across all studies are collapsed, genetic influences [on intelligence differences] account for around 50% of the variance’ (Petrill et al. 2004, taken from the Review [*Genetics of intelligence* by Deary et al. 2006](https://www.nature.com/articles/5201588?proof=trueIn)).